# How exactly is INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE atomic?

Tags: mysql, atomic

I did a bit of search, but wasn't able to find an explicit answer. Is it atomic in the sense that it either INSERTs, UPDATEs, or throws an error? If yes, is that any different from using TRANSACTIONs or, in case I'm accessing a database from my own application, some sort of a conditional along with some sort of querying function/method?

Comment: There is only one sense of 'atomic'. Your question isn't about anything.

Comment: @EJP with respect, but my question was about clearing my doubts. I also asked a couple of other questions about transactions and implementing the same logic in a programming language and whether these three things are equivalent. So I think my question was about something.

Answer (score 2):

[MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

By definition, atomicity requires that each transaction is an all or nothing. So yes it is atomic in the sense that if the data that you are trying to insert will cause a duplicate in the primary key or in the unique index, the statement will instead perform an update and not error out. I believe the proper term is an `upsert` (update/insert).

But personally, I think it is more geared towards consistency (C in ACID principle) since this ensures that the database is in a valid state (no primary key or unique constraints have been violated).

As far as `transactions` are concerned, yes it is different. There are no roll-backs, either an insert or an update will be done.